# Why are my users from different accounts able to share the data that they provide/store in the app in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have used Kotlin to create a task management app using Firebase, but the problem that I am having is that, users are able to see each others tasks and their tasks are stored in the "same account". When user 1 creates a task,  user 2 is able to see what user 1 has created and the task that is created by user 2 is in the same list as the one created by user 1. How do I stop/avoid this? I do not want my users to share data, I want them to have their data in their respective accounts.

**This is for registration:**

class RegisterPage : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityRegisterPageBinding

private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityRegisterPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait")
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    binding.backButton.setOnClickListener{
        onBackPressed()
    }

    binding.regButton.setOnClickListener{
        validateData()
    }

}

private var name =""
private var surname = ""
private var email = ""
private var password = ""
private var confirmPassword = ""

private fun validateData() {
    name = binding.regName.text.toString().trim()
    surname = binding.regSurname.text.toString().trim()
    email = binding.regEmail.text.toString().trim()
    password = binding.regCreate.text.toString().trim()
    confirmPassword = binding.regConfirm.text.toString().trim()

    if (name.isNotEmpty() && surname.isNotEmpty() && email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty() && confirmPassword.isNotEmpty()) {
        if(password == confirmPassword){
            createAccount()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please provide missing details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun createAccount(){
    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating account...")
    progressDialog.show()

    // Adding user to firebase
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnSuccessListener() {
        updateUser()
    }.addOnFailureListener{e->
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun updateUser(){
    progressDialog.setMessage("Saving...")

    val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // get curr user id
    val uid = firebaseAuth.uid

    // setup data to add in db
    val hashMap: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
    hashMap["uid"] = uid
    hashMap["name"] = name
    hashMap["surname"] = surname
    hashMap["email"] = email
    hashMap["timestamp"] = timestamp
    hashMap["profilePicture"] = ""
    hashMap["userType"] = "user"

    //set data to db
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    ref.child(uid!!).setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener {
        //Info saved, open home screen
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Account successfully created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        startActivity(Intent(this@RegisterPage, HomeScreen::class.java))
        finish()

    }.addOnFailureListener{ e ->
        //failed adding data to db
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

**This is for login:**
class LoginPage : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginPageBinding

private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityLoginPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait")
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    binding.noAcc.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this, RegisterPage::class.java))
    }

    binding.loginButton.setOnClickListener{

        validateUserData()
    }

    binding.forgotPassword.setOnClickListener{
        startActivity(Intent(this, ForgotPassword::class.java))
    }

}


private var email = ""
private var password = ""

private fun validateUserData(){
    // Input data
    email = binding.loginEmail.text.toString().trim()
    password = binding.loginPassword.text.toString().trim()

    // Validating data
    if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid email format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //Toast.makeText(this, "exception!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else if(password.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        loginUser()
    }
}

// Login firebase auth
private fun loginUser() {

    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...")
    progressDialog.show()

    /*val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // get curr user id
    val uid = firebaseAuth.uid

    // setup data to add in db
    val hashMap: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()
    hashMap["uid"] = uid
    hashMap["email"] = email
    hashMap["timestamp"] = timestamp
    hashMap["userType"] = "user"

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Logins")*/

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            // Successful login
            checkUser()

        }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
            // failed to login
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}

private fun checkUser() {
    /* Check user type - Firebase Auth
    * user - move to user dashboard
    * admin - move to admin dashboard*/

    progressDialog.setMessage("Checking account...")

    val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser!!

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    ref.child(firebaseUser.uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()

            // Get user type - user/admin
            val userType = snapshot.child("userType").value
            if(userType == "user"){
                startActivity(Intent(this@LoginPage, HomeScreen::class.java))
                finish()

            }else if (userType == "admin"){
                startActivity(Intent(this@LoginPage, HomeScreen::class.java))
                finish()

            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: can you put your code in a snipped code?

Comment: Don't paste images of code.  It makes it impossible to search for variable name usage, and its impossible to read without zooming way in if you're over 40.  Post the actual code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Hello @AlexMamo, I am using NoSql and I structured my database in the updateUser() function in RegisterPage class